# Shopping Cart And how to make session for Cart

Tags: session, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

Respected all,

Here i am trying to make a cart functionality . i am new in array creation. At my portal i have two types of pages 1) Package and 2) Product.

Now what i am trying to do with this pages, User/ customer is able to select individual item from Product page and also get complete package that contains multiple items.

Package page display list of items with quantity attribute  using Mysql and simple php code that i have declare below. when customer will select the "add this package to cart" button then i want to add this array values to Cart session array values using post method.

I need If Cart session array already have some items then new items from package will insert into Cart Session array. If not contains any item in cart then initiate cart session array.

Here i show you my testing code. where i am try to post array values and display on page. but what is the next portion if add it to cart session array.

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['cart']=array();
 include('php_scripts/db.php');
 $pkg_id='1';
 $sql="select * from `pkg_itm` where `pkg_id`='$pkg_id' order by `itm_id` ASC";
 $run_sql=mysql_query($sql);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($run_sql);

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){   
    if ( isset( $_POST['my_pkg'] ) )
    {
         echo '<table>';
             foreach ( $_POST['my_pkg'] as $diam )
            {
            // here you have access to $diam['top'] and $diam['bottom']
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '  <td>', $diam['itm'], '</td>';
            echo '  <td>', $diam['qty'], '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';


                }
        echo '</table>';


        }

 }
  ?>
  <html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
  <h1><?php echo $pkg_id;?></h1>
  <form action="" method="post" name="pkg">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
            Item Id
        </td>
        <td>
            Qty
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php     
    $i=0;  
    $my_pkg=array();  
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_sql))
    {
     ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['itm_id'];?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['itm_id'];?>" name="my_pkg[<?php echo $i;?>][itm]"> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['qty'];?>" name="my_pkg[<?php echo $i;?>][qty]" >
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php   
       // Push data to array
       $i=$i+1;
      }
     ?>
      </table>
       <input type="submit" name="submit">
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really explain but check this out. This is really helpful ..
[Multi-dimentional Array](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnJXm0POwP0&list=PLbQffSejWr3d7mP0jS62poGumqDswqATe&index=9)